# How to pass over an argument with POST method? NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post

So, as you may see I was the creator of the question "I am having this problem by passing over GET method". But now having kind of a problem with "Passing over with POST method" Here is my code to see what is going wrong. All I want to do is to print to say : "Hello (Whatever the user pass over name of).. If ExpressJS, doesn't work, can anyone show me in Javascript way?!

> Here is the code.

```
    var server = require('./server');
var router = require('./router');
var requestHandlers = require('./requestHandlers');


 var handle = {
  '/': requestHandlers.start,
  '/start': requestHandlers.start,
  '/upload': requestHandlers.upload,
  '/show': requestHandlers.show
};

var express = require('express')
var app = express()


app.post('/view/users/:name', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.desc);
    res.end();
});

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('listening on port 8000!')
})
```

**The error I get when passing over is "Cannot GET /view/users/John"**

Comment: You specify your code, and what you want, but you don't say which is the wrong result or error with your current code. Could you add that?

Comment: @Desaroll see updated question

Answer (score 2):

you can access the path variable `:name`  from req.params object

```
app.get('/view/users/:name', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.name);
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: it says: "_Cannot GET /view/users/John_"

Comment: So, what I understand the post method prints out in the console, not on the web page?

Comment: no, when you enter a url in the navigation bar use the method `get`.

Comment: But, I want to use it with POST method. I know how to use it with the GET method.

Comment: so send your data with an HTML form with method POST

Answer (score 1):

You need to add bodyParser before your routes:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

and then whatever you pass to the route, bodyParser will make it available within the request object.